How does mutation actually work? Using map under similar condtions give two different result
After doing a fetch from database, I get an array that looks as:
[{businessID: 123, 
businessName: abc, 
subscription:
"{\"subscriptionType\": \"Basic\", \"startDate\": \"2024-11-29\", \"endDate\": null}",
documents:
    "{\"documentType\": \"docPANLink\", \"documentURL\": \"uploads/businessDocs/Collor.jpg\"},
    {\"documentType\": \"docPAN\", \"documentURL\": \"uploads/businessDocs/Collor.jpg\"}"
}]

Above is just the structure. The array actaully contains about 4 objects.
and I do parsing to get subscription and documents to be object and array as:
allClientsBusinessesList.map((business) => {
  business.subscription = JSON.parse(business.subscription);
  business.documents = business.documents
    ? JSON.parse(`[${business.documents}]`).map((document) => {
        console.log(document);
        document.documentURL = fullFileURL(document.documentURL);
      })
    : [];
});

My concern is, in the outside map, I am able to mutate the properties itself. But why can't I do the same in case of the inner map. the console.log in inner map shows the value of both property for each each individual document object but then line below it doesnt seem to work at all. my frontend receives [null, null]. is it that fullFileURL is faulty?? I dont think so because when not in loop or iteration, it does indeed give a value.
And if the mutation has cause the value to be null, then how is the outer map retaining its value as both are going under same process??

With the .map() method, you're suppose to return the new value that you want the current element to be mapped (ie: "transformed") into. If you're just wanting to mutate the original array of objects, then that's what .forEach() is for, where you're not expected to return anything.
In the case of your code, you're trying to do a mix between using the return value of .map() (to update your documents array), as well as using it to just iterate through your outer list, and updating your original business objects in place. The reason why the outer mutation works is because you're business objects refer to the objects form your array. In contrast, the inner mutation doesn't work since these objects don't exist in your original array (as they're freshly created when you do JSON.parse()), and so the mutations would only appear if you linked the new array of objects to your objects from your original array in some way. You currently try to do that by updating your documents property to point to this new array with business.documents = JSON.parse(...).map(...), but since you're not returning anything from your .map() method, it returns an array of undefined values, meaning the new objects you created and mutated within the callback aren't referenced anywhere anymore once the callback is complete, and so they're lost.
I'd suggest you do one or the other, for a .map() approach, return your value, and don't mutate the original array of objects:
const res = allClientsBusinessesList.map((business) => ({
  ...business,
  subscription: JSON.parse(business.subscription),
  documents: business.documents
    ? JSON.parse(`[${business.documents}]`).map(document => ({
        ...document,
        documentURL: fullFileURL(document.documentURL)
      }))
    : []
}));

or, you can go for a mutable version which mutates the original array:
allClientsBusinessesList.forEach((business) => {
  business.subscription = JSON.parse(business.subscription);
  business.documents = business.documents ? JSON.parse(`[${business.documents}]`) : [];
  business.documents.forEach((document) => {
    document.documentURL = fullFileURL(document.documentURL);
  });
});

Keep in mind, that if allClientsBusinessesList is state, then you should use the .map() approach which doesn't mutate the original array of objects.

thanks for your explanation. but I still don't get it. The inner objects doesnt exist yet? The console.log(document) inside map however shows me the value. So isn't it like it's there then? Won't I have the documents as array of objects when parse is completed and before map takes over?

@BibekBhattarai With your code, are you logging allClientsBusinessesList? That is where you're expecting to see your result right?

The inner objects don't exist until you do JSON.parse(\[${business.documents}]`), but all this does is create a new array with objects in them, there is no connection between the objects in this new array and your original businessobjects within yourallClientsBusinessesListarray. So loggingallClientsBusinessesList` won't show you the new array unless you connect it to the objects somehow.

You do try to establish that connection by updating business.documents =, but this doesn't do much as you're setting the documents property to an array of undefined values, since when you do your .map() on the parsed array, you're not returning anything from the callback (and since the objects you modified aren't stored anywhere, they're lost). So as your callback doesn't return anything, the .map() method ends up returning a new array of [undefined, undefined]

-Nick Parsons : yes that is what i was logging. i understand that its not in the array format until the parse is done. but since .map is operating after the parse completes right, (if so) then it's there is what i think. and since its their i again make comparision that the outer works without a return but inner doesn't? although yes your code solved the issue, i still can't comprehend the why not for map without return. surely i am having some difficulty to wrap my head around this. hope i will be clear as i work with it frequently in days to come. thank you.

@BibekBhattarai The same reason you don't see the modified objects in your output is with this code: let arr = [{a: 1}]; arr[0].a = 2; arr[0] = undefined;. If you were to log arr, you'll see [undefined], the reference to the object {a: 1} in the array is replaced by undefined (in your code, that happens by the .map() callback not returning anything). Since nothing refers to the inner object anymore, the modification is lost.

with the outer .map(), you don't assign the returned array .map() produces anywhere like you do with the inner map, so the fact that you're not returning anything from the outer map doesn't impact your original array at all.
